# Prove an isomorphism exists between a group G and the direct product of two cyclic groups generated by distinct elements of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $mn$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Prove that if $G$ has an element $a$ of order $m$ and an element $b$ of order $n$, then $G \cong \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle.$

How would I go about completing this proof? I feel like I need to employ the fact that if $a$ and $b$ commute, then the order of $ab$ is a divisor of lcm$(m,n).$

**Edit after receiving some helpful hints:**
Using what @PJK suggested, the product $\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$ is of order $mn$. $G$ is also of order $mn$, and so a bijection $\phi: G \rightarrow\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$ can exist because no power of $a$ can equal a power of $b$ (besides the identity).

How can I prove that $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$ ?

Comment: **Hint:** Internal direct product of groups. $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = $? ($m$ and $n$ are relatively primes), $|\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle| =$ ? (product rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $ab$ is an element of order $mn$ in $G$. Also, $\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle$ is a product of cyclic groups of relatively prime orders and so  $\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle$ is also a cyclic group of order $mn$.

Comment: I've used the fact that $G$ and $\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle$ have order $mn$ to show that there can exist a bijection between the two.

Comment: You could simply use the fact that any two cyclic groups of equal order are isomorphic.